# Make an argument when calling php.exe in a batch file

Tags: php, file, batch-file

I want to start c:...\php.exe and add the argment c:...\upload.php"

into my batch file but anytime I do it it says wrong Paramter.

I even tried setting an argument by saying:

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1


start ""c:\...\php.exe" %1"c:\...\upload.php"%1"
```

still wont work, thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole section of the manual dedicated to [command line usage](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). Usually though, you would just specify several arguments as space separated after the script name and you can access them in your script with $argv. Example:

```
<?php print_r($argv); ?>
```

then run with

```
php.exe test.php test1 test2
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got mis-matched quotes. They're only necessary if the window title and/or command path have spaces in them. Try

```
start "" "c:\...\php.exe" "c:\...\upload.php"
      ^^---window title
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- command
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument
```